# No se puede capturar valor de combobox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un problema al querer obtener el item de un combobox que esta en otro form. 
Es decir en mi formulario principal tengo este codigo:

```
frmOtrasDeducciones frmOD = new frmOtrasDeducciones();
frmOD.lTitulo.Text = "Agregar Tipos de Mercancía";    
frmOD.cbDeduccion.SelectedValue = 3;
frmOD.ShowDialog();
```

y en la ventana que abro tengo este codigo:

```
switch (cbDeduccion.Text)
        {
            case "Mercancía":
                int ded = 3;
                DataTable merca = biss.ODedu(ded);
                dgvOtrosTipos.DataSource = merca;
                break;
            case "Otras Deducciones":
                int de = 9;
                DataTable otrasD = biss.ODedu(de);
                dgvOtrosTipos.DataSource = otrasD;
                break;
        }
```

pero en esta parte me marca un valor nulo, y por lo tanto pues ya no hace nada de lo que esta en el case.

Comment: en que contexto pones el codigo del `switch ` ? esta en algun evento en concreto

Comment: es método que hago y despues lo llamo al load del formulario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No recomiendo que accedas de forma directa a los controles entre forma de forma cruzada accediendo directamente a estos, debrias exponer funcionalidad que permita asignar los valores en los eventos correctos.

```
public class frmOtrasDeducciones  : Form 
{
    private string titulo;
    private int deducion;

    public frmOtrasDeducciones
    {
        InitalizeComponent();
    }

    public frmOtrasDeducciones(string titulo, int deducion) : this()
    {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.deducion = deducion;
    }

    public void Form_Load(...)
    {
        lTitulo.Text = this.titulo;    
        cbDeduccion.SelectedValue = this.deducion;
    }

    //resto codigo
}
```

entonces lo usarias

```
frmOtrasDeducciones frmOD = new frmOtrasDeducciones("Agregar Tipos de Mercancía", 3);
frmOD.ShowDialog();
```

De esta forma es el propio `form` quien tiene la repsonsabilidad de acceder a los controles que tiene en su diseño y mantienes encapsulada la funcionalidad

Comment: pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error, no me reconoce el valor del combobox

Comment: el control combobox lo creas en el diseñador del form ? Si pasas valores simple no necesitas usar el cbDeduccion en el switch, puedes usar directo la variable